# How to migrate to NSSecureCoding from NSCoding

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS 13 document, I find it is now advise you prefer to use NSSecureCoding other than the old NSCodng one, also there is no example to show the difference between these two protocol. I have learn the NSCoding yet, but it is a bit difficult to change it to NSSecureCoding.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of NSSecureCoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecurecoding)? It describes the difference.

Comment: Just Check it https://nshipster.com/nssecurecoding/